# Problem of compiling webpack while upgrading angular to latest version

Tags: angular, webpack

I have one demo project written in `.Net Core , Aspboilerpalte, Angualr (SPA)` which was written using `angular-cli` and it has got originally `angualr-cli.json` but I did update to latest version 6.5.0  then everything went fine except Webpack fails at 91% compilation saying that

```
91% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open `'C:\Users\myprojectpath\aspnet-core-angular\angular\node_modules\spin.js\spin.min.js'`
```

Is there any way to solve this issue or do I need to downgrade angular and use `angular-cli.json` instead?

Answer (score 0):

can you check in your package.json is there spin.js or not.

Comment: "spin.js": "^4.0.0" this is under /angular/package.json

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this: 1) **remove** **folder of spinjs** from **node_modules** 2) run: **npm install**. 
Hope this help.